# Rails memory bloat caused by too many records loaded? What can I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-management

I have views in my heroku app where I load multiple records with has_many associations within has_many associations.

Some requests are taking up over 50mb of my dyno memory (leading to out of memory errors) and I'm not sure what is the best way to resolve the problem.

I am currently already using pagination to cut down on the records loaded.

```
@items = @section.items.order(priority: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Inside my view, I am looping through the associations to display the data.

```
@items.sizes.where(active: true).order(priority: :desc).each do 
..
end

@items.addons.where(active: true).order(priority: :desc).each do 
..
end

@items.addons.sides.where(active: true).order(priority: :desc).each do 
..
end
```

On a big page, I would be loading 20+20*3+20*4+20*4*20 = 1760 records

Assuming I don't mind the slow speed, is this the reason why each request is taking up so much memory? And if so, doesn't garbage collector clean this up? In my heroku metrics, all I see is the memory bloat increasing..

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered your own question there mate :) This is also why you should keep this type of logic in the controller using `includes` to well, include items of the associated records in 1 query instead of several separate queries.

So all you do in your view is call `@items.each do` with `@items` being defined in the controller.

If I understand it correctly – The three arrays you have there in your view, are actually three different things needed to be looped and shown separately?

I hate the types of answers that just link to a bunch of tutorials, but your issues could be the result of so many different things. So, without further due:

[This is a great article](https://medium.com/@codenode/10-tips-for-eager-loading-to-avoid-n-1-queries-in-rails-2bad54456a3f) on how to achieve what you need with a lot of detailed, yet easy to grasp explanations.

[Here's an article for debugging memory bloat](http://book.scoutapp.com/memory-bloat.html).

I hope it can be to some help at least.

Comment: Pagination can also prove to be helpful in that situation. Nobody is going to access 1760 records at once. Splitting the display into several pages or using an infinite scroll approach will prevent hitting the memory on both sides (client and server). If your users expect to download this page, then render a txt or csv file server side and push it for download

Comment: I was previously using 'includes' but the bullet rails gem was giving me a warning telling me I am better off removing it... @items = @section.items.includes({addons: [:sides]}, :sizes).order(priority: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)

Comment: The guess the question I have is why isn't GC taking care of this? Assuming I do cut down on the number of records that are being loaded, at some point won't the memory still be a problem? I don't ever see the memory usage decreasing?